# Find a word in a table cell then extract text from the next cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please take a look at this **[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/120/)**. I'm working on a ajax script to parse a JSON file. One of the items (B item) in the JSON file contains the word "Sodium" in its table and I can use this script to print the table:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url.json",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {         
         var title = item.title;
         var table = item.table; 
            if (table.indexOf("Sodium") >= 0){
         $('.'+ title+'table').html(''+table+'')
            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

Since it can find the word "Sodium" in the table, I wonder if it's possible to locate which `td` the word is in and then find its next closest `td` to extract the Sodium amount which in this case is `1200 mg`? Would something like `.closest('td').text();` work? But how to choose the selector?

JSON File

```
[{"title":"A","table":"<table class=\"tablesorter\"><thead><tr><td >Ingredient<\/td><td >Amount<\/td><td>% Daily Value**<\/td><\/tr><\/thead><tbody><tr><td>Calories<\/td><td>10<\/td><td>&nbsp;<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Total Carbohydrate<\/td><td>2g<\/td><td>&lt;1<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Vitamin C<\/td><td>110mg<\/td><td>4<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Potassium<\/td><td>235mg<\/td><td>6<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Omega 6<\/td><td>1100mg<\/td><td>*<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Vitamin B<\/td><td>1200mg<\/td><td>*<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Vitamin E<\/td><td>300mg<\/td><td>*<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table>"},{"title":"B","table":"<table class=\"tablesorter\"><thead><tr><td >Ingredient<\/td><td >Amount<\/td><td>% Daily Value**<\/td><\/tr><\/thead><tbody><tr><td>Calories<\/td><td>10<\/td><td>&nbsp;<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Total Carbohydrate<\/td><td>2g<\/td><td>&lt;1<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Vitamin C<\/td><td>110mg<\/td><td>4<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Potassium<\/td><td>245mg<\/td><td>6<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Fish Oil<\/td><td>1100mg<\/td><td>*<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Sodium (from Kitchen Salt)<\/td><td>1200mg<\/td><td>*<\/td><\/tr><tr><td>Vitamin E<\/td><td>300mg<\/td><td>*<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><\/table>"}]
```

Table Structure:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Ingredient</td>
<td>Amount</td>
<td>% Daily Value**</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Calories</td>
<td>10</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Total Carbohydrate</td>
<td>2g</td>
<td>&lt;1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vitamin C</td>
<td>110mg</td>
<td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>  //************************
<td>Sodium (from Kitchen Salt)</td>
<td>1200mg</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>  //*************************
<tr>
<td>Omega 6</td>
<td>1100mg</td>
<td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vitamin B</td>
<td>1200mg</td>
<td>*</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vitamin E</td>
<td>300mg</td>
<td>*</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply search through the parsed HTML using jQuery `:contains()` selectors:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url.json",
    success: function (data) {

        $(data.query.results.json.json).each(function (index, item) {         
            var title = item.title;
            var table = item.table; 
            if (table.indexOf("Sodium") >= 0) {
                $('.'+ title+'table').html(''+table+'');
                alert($('.'+title+'table').find('td:contains(Sodium)').next().html());
            }
        });
    },
    error: function () {}
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cYFLe/121/).

That alert call will alert the contents of the `td` after the one that contains `Sodium` in its text.

Comment: Careful: `:contains` is case sensitive.